# How to configure error response formatting on Windows Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, openrasta

I am building a demo API for some sort of issue tracker using Open Rasta and ASP.NET - and deploying to a Windows Azure Web App.

The API returns detailed error information in a dedicated media-type (application/mason+json). On my local machine I get the expected error response, but on Azure I only get the error code (for instance 404) and a standard ASP.NET error message.

See for instance http://mason-issue-tracker.azurewebsites.net/projects/999 which should have returned application/mason+json but returns HTML instead.

Is there a setting somewhere in Azure to change this?

Comment: Silly question, but if it is a web .NET app, is there not some form of web.config (RE: <customerror>).  I don't know azure, but it may be a start if you have access to yours.

Comment: Thanks, but I think custom errors only enables redirects to specific error pages which is not what I need. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: I know, but you can turn it off altogether, which is what I was referring to, i.e. CustomErrors=OFF - I forget the specific syntax, as I rarely use it.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both On and Off - no changes.

Comment: Further more - its exactly the same web.config locally and on Azure. So I am assuming it must be something Azure specific since it works locally.

Comment: Cool.  Sorry - thought it was worth a shot.  Also looking to deploy some apps to azure, so I would be keen to know.

Comment: FYI - If it was remotelyonly, then you would see errors locally, but not when hosted somewhere, i.e. other then RDP'ing in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79636/discussion-between-jorn-wildt-and-anthony-horne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing setting in web.config was this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

That fixed it for me. I still do not know why it is required on Azure but not on my local machine(s).

Found the answer at http://develoq.net/2011/returning-a-body-content-with-400-http-status-code/. The setting is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497%28VS.90%29.aspx